# How to Implement In-App Subscription in Android with in-app billing library V3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I want to implement in-app subscription in my android application using V3 billing library , I have gone through many document in google but didn't get any help . Please help me to integrate in-app subscription.

Main Issue i found , How to check if user is subscribed for particular product or canceled from play store ?

Answer (score 0):

i have used this library and it works well. It also save the bought product on its own server, and after clearing app data or uninstalling. It restore the history. Please have a look in below link.

[Android In-App Billing v3 Library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3)